# Поиск через массив

Tags: javascript, база-данных, mongodb

Есть объект **student**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59402526f0149031ce5f1276"),
    "FIO" : "Test1 Test1",
    "token" : "123sdasd23dfdfqe131d332d3d12es",
    "login" : "test1",
    "password" : "test2",
    "testsSubscribes" : [
            {
                    "testId" : ObjectId("5942d0d03c5918c49f67588a"),
                    "questions" : [
                            0
                    ],
                    "testComplited" : true
            }
    ],
    "group" : "TEST"
}
```

И коллекция **tests**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5942d0d03c5918c49f67588a"),
    "forGroups" : [
            "RPZ-151",
            "RPZ-161"
    ],
    "name" : "Тест",
    "subscribers" : [
            1,
            2
    ],
    "questionsCount" : 1,
    "questions" : [

    ]
}
.....
```

Задача заключается в том чтоб через метод `find()` вывести масив тестов где **_id** теста равняется одному из **testId** поля **testsSubscribes** объекта **student**